Having an issue with Cascadeur to Blender Bridge using a Daz Model
I am trying to bring an animation from Cascadeur to Blender using the Cascadeur to Blender Add On Bridge. I began by bringing a Daz Model into Blender (4.1) using the Daz to Blender Bridge. I opened the Cascadeur Bridge and used the Import Action button to apply the animation to my Daz Model. When I do, it makes the Daz Model so tiny it took me awhile to find it, and it also changes its orientation in blender space throughout the animation. I would appreciate any ideas! Thanks. 

Sorry but we can't help with external programs or third-party addons here. This Q&A site is here to help with problems using Blender or its built-in addons only. You'll have to contact the author of the addon(s) directly or find a forum about them.

Hi John ok thanks for letting me know!
